Adding external dependencies in Pyflink and use it in UDF
I am writing a UDF which will make an API call to get back JSON payload. Here is what it looks like -
@udf(result_type=DataTypes.STRING())
def get_data():
    response = requests.get("https:api_endpoint")
    logging.info(response)
    return json.loads(response.text)

table_env.create_temporary_function("get_data", get_data)

In the source table i have - get_data as get_data(),
In the S3 sink table i have - get_data VARCHAR
I have all the dependencies in a requirement.txt file and i do a pip install -r requirements.txt --target=.
Then i zip the contents with zip -r pyflink.zip *.
When i run my Flink application, i see that it is not able to find the dependencies from the requirements.txt file.
What am i missing ? I eventually also want to include boto3 to interact with other services.

I'm not a flink user so im not sure.. but try adding the result type??  @udf(input_types=[DataTypes.STRING()], result_type=DataTypes.STRING()). Are you constrained to using flink? What are you trying to achieve?

you mean adding the input_types right? there is no input to the function. Yes i am constrained to using Flink as it reads from a Kinesis data stream and does some real time enrichment and pushed to S3 storage. so all AWS services

The problem is that the flink app is not able to find external dependencies even if i follow the process detailed here - https://github.com/aws-samples/pyflink-getting-started/tree/main/packaging.

So following this documentation the issue got resolved. Placing the dependencies in a directory doing -
pip install -r requirements.txt --target=my_deps
and add the runtime configuration as - kinesis.analytics.flink.run.options pyFiles my_deps/
This successfully gets the dependencies and Flink job runs without errors
